# Does an encoding that uses ASCII characters after 0 (; :, etc) to encode A, B, C exist?

Tags: character-encoding, hex, ascii

When decoding ASCII hex numbers, you have to take into account the fact that characters `A` to `F` do not follow `0` to `9` in the ASCII character set.

This could easily be circumvented to use the characters directly after the `9` (`;`, `:`, etc). This lead to hard to read numbers (`1F` would become `1?` for example), but very simple decoding (we only have to subtract `0x30` to get to the nibble value).

Does this encoding exist, or is it not worth the trouble?

Comment: Decoding is already quick. We assume you read from disk, so it is not few branches which cause problems. In addition hex is easier for computer language and to speak (if you need to tell a code to other people). Also it is easier for humans *ASCII encoding" are made also for human (e.g. to split "words", else we should use binary. Think about BASE64: relatively recent (and simpler) but we didn't care much: less efficient encoding were the rule.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks. In fact, I read from a serial port and the decoding code runs on an Arduino. I let the idea go and just encode in ASCII hex now, it takes a few more lines of code, but my future self will thank me ;-)

Comment: Why not using binary? or some "escaped binary" (e.g. FF is an escape, FF FF is byte FF, so you have 254 possible values for field separation, no data, etc.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi because this is part of my data header, which is all ASCII already (with STX, ETX, etc). It would mean rebuilding the entire protocol.